# When tagging a newly added question, display the number of questions with all of the already entered tags

Tags: feature-request, tags

I would like to suggest a following feature: when a user adds tags while creating a new question, display the number of questions that already have the same tags. For example, when I enter "python", "multiprocessing" and "security", I would like to know how many questions there are that have all those tags. Also, a link to a search query for those questions could be useful. This way, it could be easier to find potential duplicates.

Comment: The system already does a search when you start typing up a question. It displays the list in-between the title and the question body.

Comment: This is not exactly the same as displaying a number. If there are zero questions tagged this way, I find it pointless to look further. If there are thousands and I thought that my question is unique, this might be an incentive.